# Existing Android App Integration to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Pressing the following button is giving the error below the image.

[image]

```
Firebase
No clients were able to be added to your Firebase project for the following reasons:
An app with this package name and SHA1 is already connected to a Google project. If you have used a Google API previously, please select that project in the Connect to an existing Project list. 
Client Package Name: packagename
Client SHA1: [59:17:0C:D9:63:14:42:A5:81:13:20:F8:58:0F:96:D8:6A:65]
```

I could not find the `Connect to an existing Project list` mentioned in the error message.

I created the project in firebase by clicking "Import Google Project" button and selecting an existing google project. Later i tried adding both debug and production signature SHA1's but that did not help.

[image]

anyone faced the same issue?

EDIT: 
Today the existing project list dialog started appearing but i still get the error even if i select from the existing project list. I started thinking that this is a preview bug. :(

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After "**Import Google Project**". Click Analytics->Click Android Icon and the following screen appears.

Put your app package name and SHA-1. Download google-services.json and move to your /app/ folder. (path-to-app/app/google-services.json).

It must work!

[image]

Comment: I just followed those steps but it seem to not working in my case. I will investigate the issue further and write it here if i found a solution.

Comment: What tool of android studio is it? I cant find called "Assistant" or "Connect To Firebase" as you dont need it to automate the process if you already follow the steps.

Comment: Its coming with the version 2.2 preview announced at IO last week.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect our existing Firebase app by adding the debug Certificate Fingerprints (SHA-1) to the Android app in the project settings in the Firebase Console.

You can get the fingerprints from your debug certificate using the keytool:

```
keytool -exportcert -list -v \
-alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

Comment: I've added the SHA1 of debug signature, i think the problem is the project created long long ago within google developer console. I expect it to work after following "import existing project" flow but it did not. Also cannot find the "Connect to an existing project list" have you seen such a list? Or maybe that is the list seen after "import existing project" button.