# Can we change Firebase Account used in Android App after its published on Google Play?

Tags: android, firebase, google-play

Is it possible to change firebase account used for Analytics, Authentication & Crashlytics after app is published on app store?

I want to use developer firebase account for alpha builds and production firebase account for beta and production builds.

Is it possible?

I dont want to clutter the analytics and reports for closed alpha builds to end up in beta or production versions of app which will be used by real users.

Comment: I want to say it's not possible just from my experience but someone else may have a workaround. The only way I see it working is for Alpha versions you upload a bundle/apk pointing at a different firebase project whereas the production and beta builds you would have to reproduce

Comment: In android we have a concept called "Prodcut Flavors" where you can create multiple "google-services.json" file for each flavor of apk you generate. Kindly check and use it.

Comment: The app is not yet in beta or production track. And I just started with alpha version. And when the first beta build will be ready can I change the firebase account at that time? Forget about all alpha builds. Lets say I just dont want to clutter initial devlopment bugs out of the analytics.

Comment: Keeping same combination of (same package name +same sha1 key) in multiple accounts (like developer account and Real user account) leads to an error of key already used in different developer account error. kindly check and proceed

Comment: I am saying once I start using Real Firebase Account I will delete Dev Firebase Account. Is it going to work?

Comment: kindly refer the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/43485731/6903609

Comment: Thank you for the help I think this clear my doubt...